# Should I add Foundation and other standard frameworks in CocoaPods dependencies?

Tags: ios, dependency-management, cocoapods

I want to create `podspec` and I'm wondering what dependencies I need to add in it. The library I'm creating `podspec` file for have the only one dependency. It depends on `Foundation` framework.

As I know all newly created iOS application already have import of `Foundation` in `prefix` file. Does it mean that all apps built above `Foundation` and I don't have to add dependency on it or not? And where is the line which Apple's frameworks I need to specify as explicit dependency in `CocoaPods` and which frameworks I can rely on.

Please, clarify it to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. Any iOS app that doesn't include Foundation would be an app that would literally not be able to use a good 99% of the available frameworks in iOS. And besides, the linker error that'll arise would be pretty self explanatory.

And like you've said, by default, all iOS apps come with Foundation imported already. So it's a fair assumption any user deploying your CocoaPod will have Foundation.

Frameworks like SpriteKit, AVFoundation, CoreBluetooth, CoreLocation, etc. Should be dependencies since they're not essential to a regular app.

Comment: Btw, what about `swift`?

Comment: Same goes for Swift. By default all iOS projects include Foundation and UIKit. This includes apps written in Swift.